# DFS and depth tree

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I need to decide whether the following statement is true or false. If true, explain why, if false give a counterexample.

Let T be the depth-tree resulting from running the DFS algorithm on a graph G and a source vertex s.
G is an undirected graph with a cycle of exactly 3 vertices.
So T necessarily **does not contain** all the shortest paths from s to the other vertices in G.

I think it's true but I don't know how to prove it or to explain why

Comment: Why do you think it's true? (hint: it would be false without the assumption "G contains a cycle of exactly 3 vertices")

Comment: Also note the sentence "T necessarily does not contain..." is a bit convoluted. I suggest rewriting it in an equivalent phrasing that would be easier to prove. In particular, the negation is at a weird place in that sentence. I'd try to move it somewhere else. "T does not contain all the shortest paths" is equivalent to "There exists a path which is not in T". Then the proof becomes a simple exercise of trying to construct this path.

Comment: Also, for future questions about graph theory, I recommend https://cs.stackexchange.com instead. It's crowded with people who love graph theory, as opposed to StackOverflow which is crowded with people who love programming.

Comment: I think it's true because when we use the DFS algorithm we will go through exactly 2 edges of the cycle so we miss a shortest path using the other edge, but I can't see how I can write it formally

Comment: Yup that's very good! So, give a name to all three vertices in the cycle. Maybe a,b and c. Now there are two possible configurations: the tree goes from s to a, then from a to b and from a to c. Or it goes from s to a, then from a to b and from b to c.

Comment: yes I see now how I can write it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, because the graph G may contain *other* cycles.  There are many ways that the 3-cycle might be embedded in the tree, and it may be that *none* of the edges in the cycle are in the tree at all, so it's difficult to make a proof by dividing all the possible embeddings into a few cases.

I think the easiest way to prove this is:

- If T is a DFS tree for G rooted at s, then every edge in G is either in T, or it connects a node to an ancestor in T.
- Note that the vertices adjacent to any edge are at different heights.  For edges in the tree, they differ by 1.  For other edges they differ by at least  1.
- The sum of height changes around a cycle must be 0, since it starts and ends at the same vertex.
- It cannot be that all the height differences in the 3-cycle are of magnitude 1, because then their sum would be an odd number -- not 0.
- At least one edge in the 3-cycle must therefore have a height difference > 1.  This edge will be a short-cut to its lower vertex, since all paths in the tree can change height by at most one per step.